# problem with rewriting a wav file in python

Tags: python, file, struct, wav, wave

I have a problem with rewriting a .wav file (wave audio file). my project involves converting a wave file data into bytes of data and then reassembling a new audio file which sounds the same.

For some reason, when I try to do this with struct.pack, the result is similar, but not the same - it seems like the original data but not exactly.

note: for normal string it works, but for the type of data in which wave files are written, it doesn't.

My function for converting the original data to bytes:

```
def original_data_to_bytes_data(original_data):
"""
params: original data.
returns: all the data in bytes form, list of strings.
"""
original_data = str(''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in original_data))
bytes_data = list()
for i in range(0, len(original_data), 8):
    bytes_data.append(original_data[i:i+8])
return bytes_data
```

My function for converting the bytes to the original data:

```
def bytes_data_to_original_data(bytes_data):
"""
params: bytes_data - data, list of strings.
returns: original data.
"""
original_data =""
for i in bytes_data:
    original_data += struct.pack('i', int(i, 2))
return original_data
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "similar but not the same"? What does that actually mean?

Comment: where is code which convert to bytes of data ? Maybe you different settings.

Comment: def original_data_to_bytes_data(original_data):
    """
    params: original data.
    returns: all the data in bytes form, list of strings.
    """
    original_data = str(''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in original_data))
    bytes_data = list()
    for i in range(0, len(original_data), 8):
        bytes_data.append(original_data[i:i+8])
    return bytes_data

Comment: `code` def original_data_to_bytes_data(original_data):
    """
    params: original data.
    returns: all the data in bytes form, list of strings.
    """
    original_data = str(''.join(format(ord(i), '08b') for i in original_data))
    bytes_data = list()
    for i in range(0, len(original_data), 8):
        bytes_data.append(original_data[i:i+8])
    return bytes_data

Comment: code, data and error messages always put in question, not in comment. It will be more readable. In comment you can't format text.

Comment: you are right I am sorry, is there a way to edit my question? if not, can you still help me, please?

Comment: I don't know if there are restrictions if you have not enough points
but you should see "edit" below you question.

Comment: thanks, can you help now, please?

Comment: try `print( bytes_data_to_original_data(original_data_to_bytes_data( some_text )))` to see if you get the same data.

Comment: do you use Python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: pycharm 3.1.4 i think

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3 I get error message. On Python 2 it works without error so I assume that you also use Python 2.

---

I checked this

```
data = 'A'
result = bytes_data_to_original_data(original_data_to_bytes_data(data))
print(result)
print(type(data), type(result))
```

and it display the same text and the same typu

But when I check

```
print(data == result)
print(len(data), len(result))
print(repr(data), repr(result))
```

then it show that `data` and `result` are different

```
False
(1, 4)
("'A'", "'A\\x00\\x00\\x00'")
```

If I use `"B"` (byte) instead of `"i"` (integer) in code

```
struct.pack('B', int(i, 2))
```

then I get the same values - so wave should sound the same too.

it works also if I use bytes `b"A"` instead of string `"A"` because Python2 tread bytes as string.

---

```
def bytes_data_to_original_data(bytes_data):
    """
    params: bytes_data - data, list of strings.
    returns: original data.
    """
    original_data = ""
    for i in bytes_data:
        original_data += struct.pack('B', int(i, 2))
    return original_data
```

---

**EDIT:** In `struct.pack()` I changed `'b'` (which need values -128..127) to `'B'` (which works with values 0..255).

Comment: original_data += struct.pack('b', int(i, 2))
struct.error: byte format requires -128 <= number <= 127

Comment: first use `"i"` and check `print(data == result)` `print(len(data), len(result))` `print(repr(data), repr(result))` to see what you get as `result`

Comment: I checked other values in documentation for [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) - maybe `"B"` will works instead of `"b"`. `"B"` is for `unsigned char` which means values `0-255`

Comment: you are right ! i was supposed to use 'B'. you are my king, much love and appriciation from me <3